# Does hyperbaric oxygen therapy help treat a tendinopathy in humans?

Tags: tendinopathy

Does hyperbaric oxygen therapy help treat a tendinopathy (specifically, tendinosis) in humans?

What I have found so far:

From {1} (RCT on 56 rats done in 2012):

> Hyperbaric oxygen therapy creates a positive histological and biomechanical effect on tendon healing after Achilles tendon repair.

From {2} (RCT on 13 rabbits done in 2004):

> The results validate the effectiveness of hyperbaric oxygen therapy in the treatment of tendinopathy. Hyperbaric oxygen therapy may increase collagen synthesis and collagen cross-link formation during the early healing process.

I wonder if any study (preferably RCT) has been done on humans.

---

References:

- {1} Kuran, Fehmi Doruk, Mahmut Pekedis, H. Yıldız, F. Aydın, and N. Eliyatkın. "Effect of hyperbaric oxygen treatment on tendon healing after Achilles tendon repair: an experimental study on rats." Acta orthopaedica et traumatologica turcica 46, no. 4 (2012): 293-300. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=17124311876271806646&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 ;  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22951751
- {2} Hsu, Robert Wen-Wei, Wei-Hsiu Hsu, Ching-Lung Tai, and Kam-Fai Lee. "Effect of hyperbaric oxygen therapy on patellar tendinopathy in a rabbit model." Journal of Trauma and Acute Care Surgery 57, no. 5 (2004): 1060-1064. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10319769524500905367&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15580033